# hql query : sum of two sub-select

Tags: hibernate, hql

what's wrong with this HQL query :

```
select (
( select sum(base)/8 FROM com.agitech.erp.model.rhp.RhpEmployeRubric where ...)
 +
 ( select sum(base)/8 FROM com.agitech.erp.model.rhp.RhpEmployeRubric where ...)
 )
```

Having the exception :

```
unexpected end of subtree
```

i also try

```
select ( select sum(base)/8 FROM RhpEmployeRubric where ...) as sum1, 
       ( select sum(base)/8 FROM RhpEmployeRubric where ...) as sum2
```

same exception !

Comment: If table is same, why can't you OR the conditions & have a single  query.

Comment: can you post POJO of `RhpEmployeRubric` class so that we can refer that entity to understand table structure. (mapping xml if you are specifying associations in xml file)